# Right to left navigation drawer menu using android design support library

Tags: android, navigation, right-to-left

I'm using the android design support library and i want to know how can i have a right to left navigation drawer,I set the gravity to right but only the navigation drawer itself moved to right, I want to know how can i put the menu items on the right side ?
Navigation View :

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:foregroundGravity="right"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```

Drawer layout :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:layout_gravity="right">
```

menu :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/account"
        android:title="First Item"></item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/filter"
        android:title="Second Item"></item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/human"
        android:title="Third Item"></item>
</group>
```

and this is my drawer now :
[image: Drawer]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by adding having the DrawerLayout as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:gravity="right"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
     tools:openDrawer="right">

     <include 
         layout="@layout/app_bar_main" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView 
         android:id="@+id/nav_view"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="right" 
         android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
         app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"       
         app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and then add to your Activity **before** `setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);`:

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    }
```

This is only possible on API 17+

Result: [image]

Comment: It works perfectly on API 21, thanks , but any other idea for pre API 17 ?

Comment: @AliSadeghi for previous API's  I will have to take some more time

Comment: and something else, is there any way to have a recyclerview in this navigation drawer instead of the menu items?

Comment: @AliSadeghi the RecyclerView can be in a drawer layout no problem. here is a link for a good tutorial to help http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html

Comment: I knew this, I wanted to know if there is any way to add RecyclerView in this drawer, by the way, Thank You

Comment: How to add an overflow menu item at the left side of this menu icon?

Answer (score 2):

set direction for navigation view .

android:layoutDirection="rtl"

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLuYu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Up vote for inner_class7,

Don't forget to add : 
**android:supportsRtl="true"** in AndroidManifest.xml. It toke half of day to find.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score -1):

just add  navigationView.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
this line to align all icons are right side
and don't forget to add android:supportsRtl="true"
this line into manifest inside application.