# menu item icon rtl, and android manifest supportRTL=false

Tags: android, menu, android-manifest, navigation-drawer

I have drawer navigation set from rtl, but my icon for the menu item is ltr:
how it looks
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RORPA.png]

I want the item icon to be rtl: Like this one.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEv85.png]

but I don't want to set `android:supportsRtl="false"` to **"true"**. Is it possible? or I have to set `android:supportsRtl="true"` in my android manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576104/right-to-left-navigation-drawer-menu-using-android-design-support-library) and see inner_class7 answer(2nd one). Answer also have a screenshot. I achieved this by following the steps mentioned in that answer. If you are using this, there's no need to set supportRTL=true in manifest